# How to get items sticker in quick.db

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I always get undefined when I want to use x.st, and I'm asking this because I want to add a sticker and if I add a sticker maybe it will look more interesting
**code for buy**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

exports.execute = async (client, message, args) => {
  let userBalance = client.eco.fetchMoney(message.author.id);
  if (userBalance.amount < 1) return message.channel.send("Bruhh");
  let item = args[0];
  if (!item) return message.channel.send("enter animal name after zoobuy. example: zoobuy whale");
  let hasItem = client.anbuy[item];
  if (!hasItem || hasItem == undefined) return message.reply(`Animal with name ${item} not found`);
  let isBalanceEnough = (userBalance.amount >= hasItem.cost);                                                                          if (!isBalanceEnough) return message.reply("you need  "+hasItem.cost+" to buy this animal.");
  let buy = client.eco.removeMoney(message.author.id, hasItem.cost);

  let itemStruct = {
    name: item.toLowerCase(),
    sti: hasItem.st
  };

  client.db.push(`animal_${message.author.id}`, itemStruct);
  return message.channel.send(`Success delivery **${item}** to your zoo. you purchased **${item}** for ${hasItem.cost} .`);
};

exports.help = {
  name: "zoobuy",
  aliases: [],
  usage: `zoobuy <item>`
};
```

**code for zoo**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
exports.execute = async (client, message, args) => {

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(` ${message.author.tag} Zoo `, message.guild.iconURL)
    .setColor("#8F00FF")
    .setThumbnail()
    .setTimestamp();
  const x = client.db.get(`animal_${message.author.id}`);
if(!x) { return message.channel.send(`You don't have animals in your zoo`); }                                                        const arrayToObject = x.reduce((itemsobj, x) => {
    itemsobj[x.name] = (itemsobj[x.name] || 0) + 1;
    return itemsobj;
}, {});
const result = Object.keys(arrayToObject).map(k => embed.addField(`Animal: ${k} ${x.st}`,`Total: **${arrayToObject[k]}**`, false));


  return message.channel.send(embed);
}
exports.help = {
  name: "zoo",
  aliases: [],
  usage: `zoo`
}
```

i need add sticker because if i add sticker it looks nice